# FFMPEG not found on MACOS 10.13.6 after a brew install

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, homebrew, macos-highsierra

I want to use ffmpeg to convert a video into a gif.

I have installed it with brew using

```
brew install ffmpeg --with-fdk-aac --with-ffplay --with-freetype --with-frei0r --with-libass --with-libvo-aacenc --with-libvorbis --with-libvpx --with-opencore-amr --with-openjpeg --with-opus --with-rtmpdump --with-schroedinger --with-speex --with-theora --with-tools
```

Before that I have properly cleaned my `homebrew` as suggested [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/238295/installing-ffmpeg-with-homebrew)

First removing ffmpeg from my system:

```
$ brew uninstall ffmpeg
```

Updating all brew packages and references.

```
$ brew update
$ brew upgrade --all
$ brew cleanup
```

Installing `ffmpeg` on my system, and link it up:

```
$ brew install ffmpeg --force --with-fdk-aac --with-ffplay --with-freetype --with-frei0r --with-libass --with-libvo-aacenc --with-libvorbis --with-libvpx --with-opencore-amr --with-openjpeg --with-opus --with-rtmpdump --with-schroedinger --with-speex --with-theora --with-tools 
$ brew link ffmpeg
```

However the linking --force did not work and the link said that it was already linked but when I try

```
brew --version
```

I get:

```
-bash: /Users/my_username/Utils/ffmpeg: No such file or directory
```

Would you guys know how to fix this?

Comment: Brew doesn’t install to that folder. What happens you open a terminal and just type “ffmpeg”

Comment: @szatmary exactly the error I reported ;)

Comment: That’s not possible. Unless you have created a bash script named ffmpeg and placed it in a default path. What happens when you type “whereis ffmpeg”

Comment: @szatmary that was actually the case. This is not my laptop and yes I just checked the bash_profile and there was an alias to ffmpeg! Thanks for saving the (way too long) day! Feel free to post as answer, I will accept ;)

Comment: LBes, note that you are using some Homebrew `ffmpeg` options that are no longer supported. Please check `brew info ffmpeg` for the proper build flags (i.e., those starting with `--with`).

Comment: @szatmary - you should add an answer pointing out what was wrong.  Comments are ephemeral and cannot be "accepted".